# Build SQL query and execute

Tags: 2010, infopath, bcs, oracle

I want the user to be able to select certain checkboxes, in the background a sql query is created, depending on which selections have been made. Then a button is pressed to execute the query against an Oracle DB and results returned to page.
Because the sql query will vary in construct I don't think I can use BCS as BCS would be pre-fixed and wont work with dynamic sql queries.

Is the BCS aspect correct and is this at all possible ootb or VS?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A custom interface, with check boxes and a submit button with a dynamic query, you'll need to build a solution in Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks, am I correct about BCS and should it not be used?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think it can be customized with a dynamic query. I have mine as SQL Views and pull those in via BCS.

Comment: So do you think I could directly connect to the Oracle DB from within the Visual Studio solution?

Comment: Yes. A quick google search brings up tutorials.